# How do I run a minimal XLA C++ computation?

Tags: c++, tensorflow-xla

I'm using the XLA C++ API, and I've managed to run a simple addition, but I've no idea if I'm doing it right. There seem to be an awful lot of classes that I've not used. Here's my example

```
auto builder = new XlaBuilder("XlaBuilder");
auto one = ConstantR0(builder, 1);
auto two = ConstantR0(builder, 2);
auto res = one + two;

ValueInferenceMode value_inf_mode;
auto value_inf = new ValueInference(builder_);

auto lit = value_inf
    ->AnalyzeConstant(res, value_inf_mode)
    ->GetValue()
    ->Clone();

// I'm using `untyped_data` because I can't express arbitrary array types.
// I guess I could use `data<int32>` in this simple case
auto data = lit.untyped_data();

std::cout << ((int32*) data)[0] << std::endl;  // prints 3
```

Comment: I am not familiar with XLA at all, but `auto builder = new XlaBuilder("XlaBuilder");` this is bad because of manual memory management. I suspect `auto builder = XlaBuilder{"XlaBuilder"};` and `auto one = ConstantR0(&builder, 1);` is the correct way.

Comment: @bolov good point. This is actually cobbled together from a few functions, and there I do want manual memory management, but you're right about here

Comment: Manual memory management is very bad in C++ and should absolutely not be used (unless legacy codebase) . C++ has exceptions and so you cannot avoid memory leaks even if you think you write `new` and `delete` correctly, I guarantee you don't. There are so many hidden exit points like overloaded operators and implicit class conversions it's practically impossible to guarantee your `delete` will be reached. Unless you use RAII. That's what smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are for. I am not trying to be mean, I am trying to share knowledge that hopefully will help you.

Comment: @bolov indeed, and i didn't think you were being mean. It's helpful. I'm FFi-ing into C++ from Idris via C and so can only use a subset of C primitives. Things like smart pointers are, afaict, not possible there

Comment: Check if your environment supports exceptions. If it doesn't, then you can write memory leak free code with manual `new` / `delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I didn't actually run that computation through XLA. Here's a different approach based on a [sample harness](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/sample_harness.cc) in the XLA source code

```
XlaComputation computation = res.builder()->Build().ConsumeValueOrDie();
ExecutionProfile profile;
Literal lit = ClientLibrary::LocalClientOrDie()
    ->ExecuteAndTransfer(computation, {}, nullptr, &profile)
    .ConsumeValueOrDie();

data = lit.untyped_data()
```